# Assumptions involving product spaces

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose a random variable $X$ is distributed in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and we are given that $X' = (X_{1}', X_{2}')$ for $X_{i}$ distributed on $\mathbb{R}^{n_{i}}$. In general, what assumptions can I make on the probability space of  $(X_{1}, X_{2})$ if $X$ lives on a complete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$? What about the probability spaces for the $X_{i}$?

I'm asking because if $X_{1}, X_{2}$ also live on spaces where their $\sigma$-algebras are complete, the product $\sigma$-algebra of $(X_{1}, X_{2})$ won't be complete. So am I justified to just assume the probability measure and $\sigma$-algebra of the product space is complete, since we are given $X = (X_{1}, X_{2})$?

Similarly, if I'm just given that $X = (X_{1}, X_{2})$ is distributed on a complete probability space, am I justified in just assuming the $X_{i}$ live in a complete probability space?

Answer (score 0):

The construction you are looking for is the [product measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure).